# Mixed model realized value of random variable

Tags: mixed-model, modeling

In Andrew Gelman's book "Data Analysis using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models" , page number 258

group $j$ random intercepts $\alpha_j$ is estimated based on this expression

$$\alpha_j = \frac{n_j/\sigma_y^2}  {n_j/\sigma_y^2 + 1/\sigma_{\alpha}^2} (\hat{y_j} - X_j{\beta}) +  \frac{1/\sigma_{\alpha}^2}  {n_j/\sigma_y^2 + 1/\sigma_{\alpha}^2} {\mu_{\alpha}}$$

Here

$n_j$ number of measurements in each group $j$

$σ_y$ represents variability within groups
$σ_α$ represent variability between groups

$\mu_α$ represents unconditional average of y

What is the implication of including group variable (**Study Site ID**) as both fixed effects and random effects vs just random effects. I like to understand the difference in the context of the expression for $\alpha_j$ mentioned above.

Thanks in advance for any advice.